# Confusing C# code with Confuser does not work with language resource files (DLLs)

Tags: c#, winforms, localization, obfuscation

I have a C# project (WinForms) in Visual Studio 2012, running Windows 7 Professional 64bit.

My WinForms app comes with two languages - English and German.
Thus, in my Visual Studio project, I have two resource files (.resx) **lang.resx** (containing my default language, German) and **lang.en-GB.resx** (containing my optional language, English).

When I compile my project for .NET 3.5, VS creates two folders in my app project folder, **"de_DE"** and **"en_GB"**, and copies DLL files containing the language stuff into those two folders (both files are named "app.resources.dll").

So far, so good. My app works well, when not "confused". When run on an English copy of Windows, it shows English text, when run on a German or any other language copy of Windows, it shows German text... As expected.

Now, I am confusing my code with Confuser (found on CodePlex: https://confuser.codeplex.com/), using Confusor version 1.9 (the latest, pre-compiled, downloadable .exe version).

When I add my "app.exe" and "de-DE\app.resources.dll" and "en-GB\app.resources.dll" to confuser, the confusor **will only generate 1 confused app.resources.dll** - not 2 (one for each language / resource DLL).

That means, I cannot switch between languages as only ONE app.resources.dll seems to be considered by confuser (not both).

I guess my project setup is nothing special or outstanding (plain olde WinForm app with more than one language).

**My question is:**

How do I have to configure the confuser so that it confuses my app.exe and the two app.resources.dll files correctly?

Any help (or even hint) is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's open source, so look into the code.

Comment: I know, it's open source - but we Germans currently have a bad record on fiddling with open source software ;-) so I'd rather not mess with the source code of Confuser myself...

Answer (score 1):

On the confuser patch listings it addresses your exact issue:)
http://confuser.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/list/patches

Patch ID 14664 is about your issue, and it looks like you need to set the entries in the project file (taking an excerpt of their own site):

```
An example with language files, showing what the output should be:

Executables\Common.resources.dll -> targetfolder\common.resources.dll
Executables\de\Common.resources.dll -> targetfolder\de\common.resources.dll
Executables\fi\Common.resources.dll -> targetfolder\fi\common.resources.dll

etc.

After patching this can now be achieved with the following kind of project file:

...
<assembly path="..\Executables\Common.resources.dll" />
<assembly path="..\Executables\de\Common.resources.dll" toSubFolder="de" />
<assembly path="..\Executables\fi\Common.resources.dll" toSubFolder="fi" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot you merely rename DLLs ?

- **de-DE\app.resources.dll => de-DE_app.resources.dll**
- **en-GB\app.resources.dll => en-GB_app.resources.dll**

Comment: The DLLs are generated from my lang.resx and lang.en-GB.resx files and named "app.resouces.dll" automatically - I've looked into this in Visual Studio and I could not find any setting to control the DLL name for the embedded resource. Merely renaming them in explorer, is that what you mean? I guess that won't work since my .exe file references them.